# Adding Psql Path to Bash

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I currently have this in my bash profile:

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
source /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

And I want to add this:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

How do I add that in there?

Comment: Between the line starting with `PATH` and the one starting with `export`.  And you don't "add psql to bash" but rather "the directory containing psql to the path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it before the `export PATH` part:

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
source /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

The last part of both `PATH=..`line, reading `:$PATH` or, equivalently `:${PATH}`, makes sure you do not overwrite the existing value.

Comment: Thanks. What if I'm not working from within that Python virtualenv? Doesn't seem to be working in that case. How do I get it to work outside of that if say I'm programming in another language?

Comment: Add the line to your `.bashrc` file

Comment: And source your bashrc with `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

just add that line before `export PATH`